# SQL use CASE statement in WHERE IN clause

Tags: sql, select, switch-statement, case, where-in

Is it posible to use *case* in *where in* clause?
Something like this:

```
 DECLARE @Status VARCHAR(50);
 SET @Status='published';

 SELECT * FROM Product P    
 WHERE P.Status IN (CASE WHEN @Status='published' THEN (1,3)
                                   WHEN @Status='standby' THEN (2,5,9,6)
                                   WHEN @Status='deleted' THEN (4,5,8,10)
                                   ELSE (1,3)
                                   END)
```

This code gives the error : *Incorrect syntax near ','.*

Comment: what is the type of P.Status?

Comment: You can use `case` in a `where`, but not like that. `Case` has to return one value per statement.

Comment: @MaryamArshi: the type of P.Status is int.

Comment: @SeanCoetzee. I don't understand. Can you give me an example?

Comment: just asking, what's the point of THEN(2,5,9,6)?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No you can't use `case` and `in` like this. But you can do

```
SELECT * FROM Product P    
WHERE @Status='published' and P.Status IN (1,3)
or @Status='standby' and P.Status IN  (2,5,9,6)
or @Status='deleted' and P.Status IN (4,5,8,10)
or P.Status IN (1,3)
```

BTW you can reduce that to

```
SELECT * FROM Product P    
WHERE @Status='standby' and P.Status IN (2,5,9,6)
or @Status='deleted' and P.Status IN (4,5,8,10)
or P.Status IN (1,3)
```

since `or P.Status IN (1,3)` gives you also all records of `@Status='published' and P.Status IN (1,3)`

Comment: Don't you need parenthesis around each "or" clause? E.g. or (@Status='standby' and P.Status IN (2,5,9,6))

Comment: Don't think you need parentheses, but the last `or` statement will return false results... See this fiddle -- the 2nd record should not be returned.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9aef0/6

Comment: AND has a stronger precedence than OR. That is why you don't need parentheses in this case.

Answer (score 14):

I realize this has been answered, but there is a slight issue with the accepted solution.  It will return false positives.  Easy to fix:

```
SELECT * FROM Products P    
WHERE (@Status='published' and P.Status IN (1,3))
   or (@Status='standby' and P.Status IN  (2,5,9,6))
   or (@Status='deleted' and P.Status IN (4,5,8,10))
   or (@Status not in ('published','standby','deleted') and P.Status IN (1,2))
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9aef0/8)

Parentheses aren't needed (although perhaps easier to read hence why I included them).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use a case statement in a where clause, here is how I do it:

```
Select 
ProductID
OrderNo,
OrderType,
OrderLineNo
From Order_Detail
Where ProductID in (
Select Case when (@Varibale1 != '') 
then (Select ProductID from Product P Where .......)
Else (Select ProductID from Product)
End as ProductID
)
```

This method has worked for me time and again. try it!

Comment: It worked for me, created a temp table inserted the required products based on parameter condition and joined with temp table, deleted the temp table at last

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT  * FROM Tran_LibraryBooksTrans LBT  
 LEFT JOIN Tran_LibraryIssuedBooks LIB ON 
 CASE WHEN LBT.IssuedTo='SN' AND LBT.LIBRARYTRANSID=LIB.LIBRARYTRANSID THEN 1
      WHEN LBT.IssuedTo='SM' AND LBT.LIBRARYTRANSID=LIB.LIBRARYTRANSID THEN 1 
      WHEN LBT.IssuedTo='BO' AND LBT.LIBRARYTRANSID=LIB.LIBRARYTRANSID THEN 1
 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this way

`SELECT *
      FROM Product P
      WHERE (CASE
         WHEN @Status = 'published' THEN
          (CASE
            WHEN P.Status IN (1, 3) THEN
             'TRUE'
            ELSE
             FALSE
          END)
         WHEN @Status = 'standby' THEN
          (CASE
            WHEN P.Status IN (2, 5, 9, 6) THEN
             'TRUE'
            ELSE
             'FALSE'
          END)
         WHEN @Status = 'deleted' THEN
          (CASE
            WHEN P.Status IN (4, 5, 8, 10) THEN
             'TRUE'
            ELSE
             'FALSE'
          END)
         ELSE
          (CASE
            WHEN P.Status IN (1, 3) THEN
             'TRUE'
            ELSE
             'FALSE'
          END)
       END) = 'TRUE'`

In this way if @Status = 'published', the query will check if P.Status is among 1 or 3, it will return TRUE else 'FALSE'. This will be matched with TRUE at the end

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to my Scenario, I did "use CASE statement in WHERE IN clause" like following

```
@AdjType varchar(20) = 'Value', 
@Base varchar(20) = 'Common'
where 
(select CASE WHEN SA.IsPersentage = 0 THEN 'Value' 
       WHEN SA.IsPersentage = 1 THEN 'Presentage' END) Like @AdjType
and (Select CASE WHEN SA.IsDependOnBasicSalary = 0 THEN 'Common' 
        WHEN SA.IsDependOnBasicSalary = 1 THEN 'Basic Salary' END) like @Base
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select  * from Tran_LibraryBooksTrans LBT  left join
 Tran_LibraryIssuedBooks LIB ON   case WHEN LBT.IssuedTo='SN' AND
 LBT.LIBRARYTRANSID=LIB.LIBRARYTRANSID THEN 1 when LBT.IssuedTo='SM'
 AND LBT.LIBRARYTRANSID=LIB.LIBRARYTRANSID THEN 1 WHEN
 LBT.IssuedTo='BO' AND LBT.LIBRARYTRANSID=LIB.LIBRARYTRANSID THEN 1
 ELSE 0 END`enter code here`select  * from Tran_LibraryBooksTrans LBT 
 left join Tran_LibraryIssuedBooks LIB ON   case WHEN LBT.IssuedTo='SN'
 AND LBT.LIBRARYTRANSID=LIB.LIBRARYTRANSID THEN 1 when
 LBT.IssuedTo='SM' AND LBT.LIBRARYTRANSID=LIB.LIBRARYTRANSID THEN 1
 WHEN LBT.IssuedTo='BO' AND LBT.LIBRARYTRANSID=LIB.LIBRARYTRANSID THEN
 1 ELSE 0 END
```