# Using case when in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to use same temp table 2 times within if and else it says

> There is already an object named '#ParentLocIds' in the database.

So I tried to use case when that was suggested by the chatgpt and It's also not working that way.

What's the best way to deal with such a situation? Thank you!

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY parentLocID) AS ROWNO, * 
INTO 
    #ParentLocIds
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT parentLocID 
     FROM Locations 
     WHERE 
         CASE 
            WHEN @Role = 3 
                THEN locId IN (SELECT DISTINCT parentLocID  
                               FROM Locations 
                               WHERE locId IN (SELECT LocId FROM #EmpRole))
            WHEN @Role = 4 
                THEN locId IN (SELECT DISTINCT parentLocID  
                               FROM Locations 
                               WHERE locId IN (SELECT DISTINCT parentLocID  
                                               FROM Locations 
                                               WHERE locId IN (SELECT LocId FROM #EmpRole)))
```

I'm trying to use same temp table name in different branches. I don't want to create multiple tables of same thing.

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression*, it returns a scalar value, not a boolean result. Don't use a `CASE` like that, use explicit `AND`/`OR` logic.

Comment: The case expression lacks a terminating `end`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL use CASE statement in WHERE IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271853/sql-use-case-statement-in-where-in-clause)

Comment: `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY parentLocID) AS ROWNO, * 
 INTO #ParentLocIds
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT parentLocID 
   FROM Locations 
   WHERE locId IN (SELECT Distinct parentLocID  from Locations where locId in (SELECT LocId FROM #EmpRole) AND @Role = 3) 
   OR
   locId IN (SELECT Distinct parentLocID  from Locations where locId in (SELECT Distinct parentLocID  from Locations where locId in (SELECT LocId FROM #EmpRole)) AND @Role = 4))`

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should avoid SELECT INTO altogether, it's kinda of an antipattern, better to create your table manually and then insert into it. Also, your code doesn't work, you should do something like: `WHERE 1 = case when something and locid in ... then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: Start your script with `drop table if exists #ParentLocIds`; that will get rid of the "there is already a table named '#ParentLocIds'" problem

Comment: Also if you had some sample data to play with that would be really helpful. I have a feeling there may be simpler ways to approach your problem, but it would depend on the schemas and data in the tables in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
DECLARE @Role  int = 1
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY parentLocID) AS ROWNO, *      
INTO #ParentLocIds  
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT parentLocID            
FROM Locations              
WHERE (locId IN (SELECT Distinct parentLocID  from Locations where locId in (SELECT LocId FROM #EmpRole) AND @Role = 3))
OR (locId IN (SELECT Distinct parentLocID  
            from Locations 
            where locId in (SELECT Distinct parentLocID  from Locations where locId in (SELECT LocId FROM #EmpRole)) 
    AND @Role = 4))
) AS A
```

Answer (score 1):

you can structure your query to ensure that the temporary table is only created once. Instead of using a CASE statement within the `WHERE` clause, you can construct your query based on the value of `@Role`

```
-- Drop the temp table if exists
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ParentLocIds') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ParentLocIds;

-- Define table #ParentLocIds
CREATE TABLE #ParentLocIds (
    ROWNO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    parentLocID INT
);

-- Insert into TempTable based on value @Role
IF @Role = 3
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #ParentLocIds (parentLocID)
    SELECT DISTINCT parentLocID
    FROM Locations
    WHERE locId IN (SELECT Distinct parentLocID FROM Locations WHERE locId IN (SELECT LocId FROM #EmpRole));
END
ELSE IF @Role = 4
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #ParentLocIds (parentLocID)
    SELECT DISTINCT parentLocID
    FROM Locations
    WHERE locId IN (SELECT Distinct parentLocID FROM Locations WHERE locId IN (SELECT Distinct parentLocID FROM Locations WHERE locId IN (SELECT LocId FROM #EmpRole)));
END

-- Final table after inserting data
SELECT * FROM #ParentLocIds;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can abstract the parent locations for each role into a table or view named, say, `RoleLocations`, mapping roles to locations, then you could simply query that relation in your query. Something that looks like:

| Role | ParentLocId |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| .. | ... |

and then your query would be:

```
select 
    row_number() over (order by ParentLocId) as rowno,
    ParentLocId
from RoleLocations
where Role = @Role
```

Without knowing what's in `#EmpRole` or how it's populated, I don't know if that's feasible, but that's where my head went.

Comment: this makes no snese if @ role is 1 you would get an result if rows existed, but in his initial attempt he wouldn't never get rows back with that role

Comment: Changed it to reflect the two _visible_ branches of the case expression.

Comment: you did understand role is not compared to a column, it is only  a flag, if 3 show some  rows if 4 show some other row, if anything else so none, you haven't a column named role and you need no mapping